# Что такое value semantics?

Tags: c++

> Limitation
>
> The erase–remove idiom cannot be used for containers that
> return const_iterator (e.g.: set)[6]
>
> std::remove and/or std::remove_if do not maintain elements that are
> removed (unlike std::partition, std::stable_partition). Thus,
> erase–remove can only be used with containers holding elements with
> full value semantics without incurring resource leaks.

Это параграф из [статьи](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom). Скажите, что означает full value semantics в контексте этой статьи? Я слышал только о move semantics.

Comment: По контексту похоже, что имеется в виду тип, который хранится по значению, а не по ссылке или указателю. То есть это будет работать с типом `std::vector<SomeClass>`, но не с `std::vector<SomeClass*>` и `std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<SomeClass>>`.

Comment: С указателями тоже будет работать если эти указатели не используются для управления владением.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, конечно, согласен. Erase-remove не вызывает оператор delete.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В таком контексте я это слово раньше не слышал. (Чаще попадается [в таком](https://stackoverflow.com/q/166033/2752075).)

Википедия сама же и объясняет, что она имеет в виду: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_semantics

> In computer science, having value semantics ... means for an object that only its value counts, not its identity.

То есть класс (тип) написан и используется так, что неважно, где он копируется и сколько раз (в смысле неважно с точки зрения корректности, может быть важно с точки зрения производительности).

Чтобы оно так работало, класс должен соответствовать [правилу 3/5/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). (Я бы так и сформулировал, и не приплетал бы value semantics.)

Comment: в смысле "класс копируется"???

Comment: @AlexanderSivak Имеются в ввиду объекты такого класса.